# RDLC's Table borders till end of the body

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssrs-2016, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I am generating a Sale Invoice through RDLC. In that I have a table that consists of item description, rate, qty, amount.

I want to set the borders of the table till end of the  body though items are not up to page size. I.e if page size capacity is 10 items but sale invoice contains only 2 items, my report should display 2 items but borders should display for 10 items.

How can I achieve this.

Using ASP.Net, C#, RDLC for Webforms

Comment: I'd be inclined to go for adding blank, dummy items to make up the capacity of the page, but this does seem like a bit of a kludge.

Comment: I would set the borders with a rectangle fit to page and then place your table inside the rectangle and limit it to 10 or make it so that 10 items per page is ideal.

Comment: We want borders at column level. Keeping inside rectangle and adjusting it to fit to the body will give only table borders, instead i would choose borders to the body itself.

Comment: I am able to fill dataset with null values by using formula pagesize - (rows.count % pagesize) but it taking 2nd and 3rd page, though no data is available to print